# Printing all values to a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a small script that pulls some unnecessary columns from a text file that I'm working with. I'm not sure how to get it to print to a text file without loss of data.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

df = pd.read_table('newclass.txt', sep=r'\s+')
newcol=['A']
df = df[newcol]

for i in df:
    print df
```

But this only gives a text file that looks like,
(for example)

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
...
value###
value###
```

...where ### are just higher values at the end of the list. As you can see it fails to show all of the values (the middle of the list). How do I get a printout of all the values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) on the dataframe (you just need to specify that you want a space as the delimiter):

```
path = "fixedfile.txt"
df.to_csv(path, sep=" ", index=False)
```

Comment: That worked but would it be possible to have it printed out without the index values alongside?

Comment: @Matt you can just use `index=False`. I added a link to the `to_csv` docs, which can answer more of your questions.

Comment: @Matt if this works for you, you should click the checkmark so everyone can tell your question is resolved.

Comment: @ Jeff Tratner - I'm actually having issues the script seems to be cutting out the first few values.

Comment: @Matt you would need to post more code to figure that out. Does `df.head()` show what you expect?

Comment: df.head() prints the first 5 values of my data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30231/discussion-between-jeff-tratner-and-matt)

Answer (score 0):

Initially my problem was that I was getting a minimized output of all my data, secondly I didn't want an index in front of my first column. My solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

df = pd.read_table('newclass.txt',sep='\s+')
newcol=['Mon-id']
df = df[newcol]

print df.to_string(index=False)
```

According to the documentation pandas automatically reduces it's output unless you specify it not to with the `.to_string` command.

Comment: Right, `to_string` is what you want if you want to print it. `to_csv` outputs it directly to a file instead (or you can pass it a `StringIO` instance if you want to get a string instead)